# indexOf() not working as expected, function keeps adding duplicates - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

const handleClick = (day) => {
  let newArray = [...dates];
  let indexItem = newArray.indexOf(day);
  indexItem === -1 ? newArray.push(day) : newArray.splice(indexItem, 1);
  setDates(newArray);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(dates);
}, [dates]);

return(
  <DayPicker selectedDays={dates} onDayClick={handleClick} />
)
```

Is it possible to update my code so that state contains only dates that are clicked once and removed when clicked twice?

So kind of being able to toggle dates in state.

My function only removes the element after it is added 2 times, so it is not possible atm to remove duplicates out of the array.

The `day` parameter in `handleClick` returns values as strings like:

```
Fri Mar 05 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

When i `console.log()` dates in browser this is what it looks like:

```
0: Wed Mar 03 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
1: Wed Mar 10 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
2: Wed Mar 17 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
3: Wed Mar 03 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
4: Wed Mar 10 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
5: Wed Mar 17 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
```

You can see the duplicates, and if i click the same days again than the result would be

```
0: Wed Mar 03 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
1: Wed Mar 10 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
2: Wed Mar 17 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
```

instead of

```
[]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the module
https://react-day-picker.js.org/.
But the `day` parameter in the `function` returns a `string` as mentioned in question above :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I updated my question with more details about the output in console, if you could take a look :)

Comment: You call `array .splice()` and ignore the return value. So you ever only add elements. I made it a habit of visiting the [mdn docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) whenever I use a function the details of which I easily forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the argument the library passes to the click handler is a Date, not a string, so `indexOf` doesn't work - different objects aren't `===` to each other, even if they contain the same values. So, the found index is always -1, and duplicate objects get added to state.

I'd make an array of *timestamps* (numbers) instead, so that duplicates can easily be detected:

```
const [timestamps, setTimestamps] = React.useState([]);

const handleClick = (clickedDate) => {
    const clickedTimestamp = clickedDate.getTime();
    const index = timestamps.indexOf(clickedTimestamp);
    if (index === -1) {
        setTimestamps([...timestamps, clickedTimestamp]);
    } else {
        setTimestamps(
            timestamps.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
        );
    }
};
```

```
<DayPicker
    selectedDays={timestamps.map(t => new Date(t))}
    onDayClick={handleClick}
/>
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot for looking into it! The only problem i have with this approach is at the `post request` stage to mongoDB. The array of `timestamps (numbers)` is not added to the database. The approach of sameHanwar converts the `numbers`again to the `strings`. I could do that seperately with your solution as well off course. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

i think more appropriate way to achieve that is to convert the selected day to a timestamp format and then compare it to the state.

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (day) => {
    let currentDay = new Date(day).getTime();
    let newArray = [...dates];
    let indexItem = newArray.indexOf(currentDay);

    indexItem === -1 ? newArray.push(currentDay) : newArray.splice(indexItem, 1);
    setDates(newArray);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dates);
  }, [dates]);

  const selectedDates = dates && dates.map((date) => new Date(date));

  return <DayPicker selectedDays={selectedDates} onDayClick={handleClick} />;
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Works like a charm and this way i can immediately post the `timestamps` as `strings` to mongoDB. Thanks again for your time :)